# EulerAngles Unity in if statement does not work proper with some values C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform, euler-angles

I have a car game, and it is only possible to drive along the x and the z axis.
If the car drives to positiv z (rotation  == 0) then it has to do something, if it drives to positive x (rotation == 90) then it has to do something else, and so on.

```
    if (transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y == 0)
    {
        richtung = 0;
        Debug.Log("north");
    }

    if (transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y == 90)
    {
        richtung = 1;
        Debug.Log("east");
    }

    if (transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y == -180 || transform.rotation.y == 180)
    {
        richtung = 2;
        Debug.Log("south");
    }

    if (transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y == -90)
    {
        richtung = 3;
        Debug.Log("west");
    }
```

It works with north and east, but south and west does not. Even if I start the program with a car driving with rotation == -180 || 180.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: The Euler angles are between 0 to 360 degrees.
therefore, when you compare it to -180 it will always be false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use non-negative value, as the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html) states, it must be between 0 and 360.

```
if (transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y == 180)
{
    richtung = 2;
    Debug.Log("south");
}

if (transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y == 270)
{
    richtung = 3;
    Debug.Log("west");
}
```

You had the third case almost right, but unfortunately you used `transform.rotation.y` instead of `transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y`.

As @Everts pointed out, it would be better to compare the values with a "epsilon" value, because `float` and `double` are not perfectly precise (because of the format in which they are stored in memory).

```
Math.Abs(transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y - 180) < 0.001
```

Comment: This is really unlikely to work as comparing two floats barely works (you'd use a margin of approximation).

Comment: `Mathf.Approximately()`

Answer (score 2):

Since you are only setting the vehicle in four direction, you can set more at the same time.

Let's consider you use the A and D keys to rotate the vehicle, and the vehicle starts with richtung = 0.

```
public enum Direction { North, East, South, West }
public Direction VehicleDirection{ get{ return (Direction)richtung; } } 
private int richtung = 0;
void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
    {
        if(++richtung == 4){ richtung == 0; }
    }
    else if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
    {
       if(--richtung < 0){ richtung == 3; }
    }
}
```

Now you don't need to care about the rotation since you can now it with the value of richtung. Anywhere else, you can use the VehicleDirection to indicate more explicitely where it is heading.

Comment: I think you left two answers by mistake

Comment: Indeed I did do it